# Copy property of each element of array1 into array2

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I have array1 that contains 1 char in each element.

What I need, is to get the value of array1[i].charCodeAt(); and put it in array2.
Easy to do it, with a for statement.

```
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        y[i]= x[i].charCodeAt();
         }
```

I did some research but nothing that explain this case:
Is it possible to populate array2 by some sort of **destructuring**, or what I am asking is not supported in js? For example:

```
    array1 =['a','b','c'];
    array2 = [];
    array2 = array1[].charCodeAt. 
conole.log('The first char has code ' + array2[0]); // The first letter has code 97.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't creating separate standalone variables, so destructuring isn't what you're looking for - but, you can use `.map` to transform the first array into the second:

```js
const array1 =['a','b','c'];
const array2 = array1.map(char => char.charCodeAt(0));
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const array1 = ['a','b','c'];
const array2 = array1.map(c => c.charCodeAt());

console.log(array2);
```